# None of my Browser's are pulling CSS divDisplay code but CodePen does

Tags: html, css

I'm taking a Coursera course called, "Welcome to the Web Design for Everybody (Basics of Web Development and Coding) Specialization" and am new to coding.  On my computer I have created a CSS folder and named my CSS code file `divDisplay.css` and I also created an HTML folder and named my HTML5 code file `divDisplay.html`. When I open my code in any Browser like Chrome, FireFox or Microsoft Edge, the code is there but the CSS colors and `divDisplay` are not there see here: Copy and past this into your broswer.

```
file:///K:/COURSERAWEBDEVELOPMENT/divDisplay.html
```

When I copy and past my CSS and HTML code into CodePen it works just fine.  It should look this this.   https://codepen.io/LuRocks/pen/RwbQxZj

When I open the code in Chrome I go and right click on page and select INSPECT and when you go to far right and click on the CONSOLE tab it gives me an error saying this:

```
Failed to load resource: divDisplay.css:1 net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

Please help. Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Luciana Castillo

Don't know what else to do.

In Sublime Text3 here is my CSS3 code: Saved under divDisplay.css

```
span{
height:50px;
width:75px;
background:#00ff00;
}   
div{
height:100px;
width:45%;
background:#00ffff;

}

p{
background:#ff00ff;
width: 200px;
height:100px;
}
```

In Sublime Text3 here is  my HTML5 code: Saved under divDisplay.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset= "UTF-8">
<title>Div Display Example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/divDisplay.css">
</head>
<body>

<span>Span A</span>
<span>Span B</span>
<span>Span C</span>
<hr>
<div>Div A</div>
<div>Div B</div>
<div>Div C</div>
<hr>
<p>Paragraph A</p>
<p>Paragraph B</p>
<p>Paragraph C</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I expect the output to look like this https://codepen.io/LuRocks/pen/RwbQxZj
but it doesn't and instead the output looks like this. Copy and paste link into your browser.

```
file:///K:/COURSERAWEBDEVELOPMENT/divDisplay.html
```

Comment: First of all, `file:///K:/COURSERAWEBDEVELOPMENT/divDisplay.html` is your local address and can't be opened by anyone else except you. And, as I understand, your `divDisplay.html` file is in a folder named HTML and `divDisplay.css` is in the folder CSS. Are these two folders in same folder?

Comment: Actually I figured it out.  I know what I was doing wrong in my code.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Missed css file path. Link will be `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/divDisplay.css">`

Comment: Actually I figured it out.  I know what I was doing wrong in my code.  Thank you so much.